# Resolving invite and getting guild id

Tags: java, discord-jda

I'm looking into possibilities with resolving posted invites. 
Using java and the JDA (Java Discord API)

This is what I've currently got:

```java
    private boolean checkPinewoodInviteFilter(Message message) {
        final boolean[] isPinewoodGuild = {false};
        Invite.resolve(message.getJDA(), message.getInvites().get(0)).queue(v-> {
            System.out.println("GUILD NAME: " + v.getGuild().getName());
            System.out.println("GUILD MEMBERS: " + v.getGuild().getMemberCount());
            System.out.println("GUILD ONLINE: " + v.getGuild().getOnlineCount());

            if (Constants.guilds.contains(v.getGuild().getId())) {
                System.out.println("PINEWOOD GUILD FOUND ");
                isPinewoodGuild[0] = true;
            }
        });
        return isPinewoodGuild[0];
    }
```

But it doesn't give any invite as of right now (Using JDA 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few weeks, I've found out a working solution:

```java
private void checkPinewoodInviteFilter(Message message, DatabaseEventHolder databaseEventHolder) {
    for (String i : message.getInvites()) {
        Invite.resolve(message.getJDA(), i).queue(v-> {
            if (!Constants.guilds.contains(v.getGuild().getId())) {
                message.delete().queue();
                warnUser(message, databaseEventHolder.getGuild(), "**AUTOMOD**: Filter was activated!\n**Type**: " + "``INVITE``\n" +
                    "**Guild**: " + v.getGuild().getName() + "\n" +
                    "**Invite**: [Click here!](" + v.getURL() + ")\n" +
                    "**Inviter**:" + v.getInviter());
            }
        });
    }
}
```